# devkitARM 3DS Makefile error: uname

Tags: c, devkitpro

I'm trying to build a `.3dsx` for 3DS Homebrew, but I get the same error with all of my builds:

[image: picture of error in console]

It doesn't matter what project I try to `make`, I always get this error involving `uname`.

[image: my uname]

Here's my Makefile:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.SUFFIXES:
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ifeq ($(strip $(DEVKITARM)),)
$(error "Please set DEVKITARM in your environment. export DEVKITARM=<path to>devkitARM")
endif
TOPDIR ?= $(CURDIR)
include $(DEVKITARM)/3ds_rules
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TARGET is the name of the output
# BUILD is the directory where object files & intermediate files will be placed
# SOURCES is a list of directories containing source code
# DATA is a list of directories containing data files
# INCLUDES is a list of directories containing header files
#
# NO_SMDH: if set to anything, no SMDH file is generated.
# APP_TITLE is the name of the app stored in the SMDH file (Optional)
# APP_DESCRIPTION is the description of the app stored in the SMDH file (Optional)
# APP_AUTHOR is the author of the app stored in the SMDH file (Optional)
# ICON is the filename of the icon (.png), relative to the project folder.
#   If not set, it attempts to use one of the following (in this order):
#     - <Project name>.png
#     - icon.png
#     - <libctru folder>/default_icon.png
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TARGET          :=  $(notdir $(CURDIR))
BUILD           :=  build
SOURCES         :=  src
DATA            :=  data
INCLUDES        :=  include

APP_TITLE       :=  Savegame Manager
APP_DESCRIPTION :=  Manage the savegame of your game.\nSD Card Required
APP_AUTHOR      :=  phase
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# options for code generation
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ARCH    :=  -march=armv6k -mtune=mpcore -mfloat-abi=hard

CFLAGS  :=  -g -Wall -O2 -mword-relocations \
            -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math \
            $(ARCH)

CFLAGS  +=  $(INCLUDE) -DARM11 -D_3DS

CXXFLAGS    := $(CFLAGS) -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++11

ASFLAGS :=  -g $(ARCH)
LDFLAGS =   -specs=3dsx.specs -g $(ARCH) -Wl,-Map,$(notdir $*.map)

LIBS    := -lctru -lm

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# list of directories containing libraries, this must be the top level containing
# include and lib
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LIBDIRS := $(CTRULIB)


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# no real need to edit anything past this point unless you need to add additional
# rules for different file extensions
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ifneq ($(BUILD),$(notdir $(CURDIR)))
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export OUTPUT   :=  $(CURDIR)/$(TARGET)
export TOPDIR   :=  $(CURDIR)

export VPATH    :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(CURDIR)/$(dir)) \
            $(foreach dir,$(DATA),$(CURDIR)/$(dir))

export DEPSDIR  :=  $(CURDIR)/$(BUILD)

CFILES      :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c)))
CPPFILES    :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp)))
SFILES      :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.s)))
BINFILES    :=  $(foreach dir,$(DATA),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.*)))

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# use CXX for linking C++ projects, CC for standard C
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ifeq ($(strip $(CPPFILES)),)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    export LD   :=  $(CC)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
else
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    export LD   :=  $(CXX)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
endif
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export OFILES   :=  $(addsuffix .o,$(BINFILES)) \
            $(CPPFILES:.cpp=.o) $(CFILES:.c=.o) $(SFILES:.s=.o)

export INCLUDE  :=  $(foreach dir,$(INCLUDES),-I$(CURDIR)/$(dir)) \
            $(foreach dir,$(LIBDIRS),-I$(dir)/include) \
            -I$(CURDIR)/$(BUILD)

export LIBPATHS :=  $(foreach dir,$(LIBDIRS),-L$(dir)/lib)

ifeq ($(strip $(ICON)),)
    icons := $(wildcard *.png)
    ifneq (,$(findstring $(TARGET).png,$(icons)))
        export APP_ICON := $(TOPDIR)/$(TARGET).png
    else
        ifneq (,$(findstring icon.png,$(icons)))
            export APP_ICON := $(TOPDIR)/icon.png
        endif
    endif
else
    export APP_ICON := $(TOPDIR)/$(ICON)
endif

ifeq ($(strip $(NO_SMDH)),)
    export _3DSXFLAGS += --smdh=$(CURDIR)/$(TARGET).smdh
endif

.PHONY: $(BUILD) clean all

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
all: $(BUILD)

$(BUILD):
    @[ -d $@ ] || mkdir -p $@
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $(BUILD) -f $(CURDIR)/Makefile

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
clean:
    @echo clean ...
    @rm -fr $(BUILD) $(TARGET).3dsx $(OUTPUT).smdh $(TARGET).elf


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
else

DEPENDS :=  $(OFILES:.o=.d)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# main targets
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ifeq ($(strip $(NO_SMDH)),)
$(OUTPUT).3dsx  :   $(OUTPUT).elf $(OUTPUT).smdh
else
$(OUTPUT).3dsx  :   $(OUTPUT).elf
endif
$(OUTPUT).elf   :   $(OFILES)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# you need a rule like this for each extension you use as binary data
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%.bin.o :   %.bin
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(notdir $<)
    @$(bin2o)

# WARNING: This is not the right way to do this! TODO: Do it right!
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%.vsh.o :   %.vsh
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(notdir $<)
    @python $(AEMSTRO)/aemstro_as.py $< ../$(notdir $<).shbin
    @bin2s ../$(notdir $<).shbin | $(PREFIX)as -o $@
    @echo "extern const u8" `(echo $(notdir $<).shbin | sed -e 's/^\([0-9]\)/_\1/' | tr . _)`"_end[];" > `(echo $(notdir $<).shbin | tr . _)`.h
    @echo "extern const u8" `(echo $(notdir $<).shbin | sed -e 's/^\([0-9]\)/_\1/' | tr . _)`"[];" >> `(echo $(notdir $<).shbin | tr . _)`.h
    @echo "extern const u32" `(echo $(notdir $<).shbin | sed -e 's/^\([0-9]\)/_\1/' | tr . _)`_size";" >> `(echo $(notdir $<).shbin | tr . _)`.h
    @rm ../$(notdir $<).shbin

-include $(DEPENDS)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
endif
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The C code itself shouldn't matter, since I get this error with every project I try to build.

Comment: do not use `.SUFFIXES:`  as that eliminates/overrided that default ordering of files, which since the makefile does not set a new ordering, will create problems for the make utility

Comment: have you executed the make with the '-d' parameter to yield a listing of each thing the make utility tries?   Where did it show the makefile crashing?  The makefile contains a recursive call to make, so that call should (probably) also have the '-d' parameter

Comment: please post the contents of the `include $(DEVKITARM)/3ds_rules` file.  what is the macro DEVKITARM defined as?  What ever it is defined as, it is not defined within the bounds of the makefile.